# Create JIRA Issue with REST API via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to create a JIRA issue via Powershell.

Here's my code.

```
function ConvertTo-Base64($string) {
$bytes  = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($string);
$encoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes);
return $encoded;
}

function Get-HttpBasicHeader([string]$username, [string]$password, $Headers = @{}) {
    $b64 = ConvertTo-Base64 "$($username):$($Password)"
    $Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic $b64"
    $Headers["X-Atlassian-Token"] = "nocheck"
    return $Headers
}

$restapiuri = "https://baseurl/rest/api/2/issue/"
$headers = Get-HttpBasicHeader "user" "password"

$body = ('
{
    "fields":
    {
        "project":
        {
            "id": "10402"
        },

        "summary": "Test",

        "description": "Test",

        "duedate": "2019-05-11",

        "issuetype":
        {
            "id": "3"
        },

        "reporter":
        {
            "name": "user"
        },

        "priority":
        {
            "id": "10101"
        },

        "customfield_11403": "Test",

        "security":
        {
            "id": "11213"
        },

        "components":
        [
            {           
                "id": "10805"
            }
        ]
    }
}')

Invoke-RestMethod -uri $restapiuri -Headers $headers -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body
```

The JSON part of it runs fine as I've tried it using Postman and the issue got created.

In Powershell however, I always get a 400 bad request returned. Does anyone got any ideas why this might be?

Thanks!

EDIT: code sample according to answer

```
$body = @{

    "fields" = @{

        "project" = @{

            "id" = "10402";
        }

        "summary" = "Test";

        "description" = "Test";

        "duedate" = "2019-05-11";

        "issuetype" = @{

            "id" = "3";
        }

        "reporter" = @{

            "name" = "user";
        }

        "priority" = @{

            "id" = "10101";
        }

        "customfield_11403" = "Test";

        "security" = @{

            "id" = "11213";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s the problem.

$restapiuri = "https://baseurl/rest/api/2/issue/"

should be

$restapiuri = "https://baseurl/rest/api/2/issue"

After this change, it finally worked! The extra / is something PowerShell doesn’t seem to enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Invoke-RestMethod to consume REST-APIs. Save the JSON to a string and use that as the body, 
ex:

```
$body = @'
{
    "fields":
    {
        "project":
        {
            "id": "10402"
        },

        "summary": "Test",

        "description": "Test",

        "duedate": "2019-05-11",

        "issuetype":
        {
            "id": "3"
        },

        "reporter":
        {
            "name": "user"
        },

        "priority":
        {
            "id": "10101"
        },

        "customfield_11403": "Test",

        "security":
        {
            "id": "11213"
        },

        "components":
        [
            {           
                "id": "10805"
            }
        ]
    }
}
'@

Invoke-RestMethod -uri $restapiuri -Headers $headers -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Please see my edit in my original post. I still get the bad request error. I also had to get rid of the component setting because I wasn't able to get it working. There was always a syntax error with the [] brackets.

Comment: thanks for your time and effort! unfortunately, it still returns 400 bad request :/

Comment: Hey @rAJ someone at the Atlassian Community was able to point out my mistake. It was the extra / at the end of my rest uri. Everything else would’ve worked the way it was. Thanks for your time and effort nonetheless though :)